# Many database queries or complicated logic?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, performance

Say, we have two models, Author, Book. To get some authors' **latest** books, we can:

Option 1

```
def get_books1():
    authors = Author.objects.filter(*condition*)
    books = {}
    for author in authors:
        # maybe lots of queries
        # simple query
        book = Book.objects.filter(author=author).order_by("-pubdate")[:1] 
        if book:
            book = book[0]
        else:
            continue
        books.update({
            "book.name": {
                "name": book.name,
                "pageno": book.pageno,
                "pubdate": book.pubdate,
                "author_name": author.name,
            }
        })
    # we got books
```

Option 2:

```
def get_books2():
    authors = Author.objects.filter(*condition*)
    # a complicated query, but only once
    _books = Book.objects.filter(author__in=authors).order_by("-pubdate")
    books = {}
    # a complicated logic to process the data(ordering, discarding, etc.)
    for book in _books:
        if book not in books:
            books[book.name] = {
                "name": book.name,
                "pageno": book.pageno,
                "pubdate": book.pubdate,
                "author_name": book.author.name,
            }
        else:
            if book.pubdate > books.get(book.name).get("pubdate"):
                books[book.name] = {
                    "name": book.name,
                    "pageno": book.pageno,
                    "pubdate": book.pubdate,
                    "author_name": book.author.name,
                }
    # we got books
```

if there're N authors in this *condition*, we have N+1 queries for Option 1,
while 2 queries for Option 2.

For performance(DB IO vs. memory processing), which should be preferred? Should we always choose Option 2? Or it depends on N, and the system(memory wise or IO wise)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the Django documentation on [QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/):

> Be cautious about using nested queries and understand your database server’s performance characteristics (if in doubt, benchmark!). Some database backends, **most notably MySQL**, don’t optimize nested queries very well. It is more efficient, in those cases, to extract a list of values and then pass that into the second query. **That is, execute two queries instead of one:**

Answering your question depends on the database backend, the indexes on the table (see your Django models / fields), et cetera.

In MySQL it's sometimes faster to perform several simple SELECT queries rather than creating one bulky query that gathers everything. If your condition for Authors narrows N down to a small number, it may be that Option 1 performs better than Option 2. That having been said, you need to profile the performance of the queries and see what performs better.